ImportError: cannot import name 'runtime_version' from 'google.protobuf'
PS D:\RealTimeObjectDetection> python Tensorflow/models/research/object_detection/model_main_tf2.py --model_dir=Tensorflow/workspace/models/my_ssd_mobnet --pipeline_config_path=Tensorflow/workspace/models/my_ssd_mobnet/pipeline.config --num_train_steps=10000
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\RealTimeObjectDetection\Tensorflow\models\research\object_detection\model_main_tf2.py", line 31, in <module>
    import model_lib_v2
  File "D:\RealTimeObjectDetection\Tensorflow\models\research\object_detection\model_lib_v2.py", line 29, in <module>
    import eval_util
  File "D:\RealTimeObjectDetection\Tensorflow\models\research\object_detection\eval_util.py", line 35, in <module>
    from object_detection.metrics import coco_evaluation
  File "D:\RealTimeObjectDetection\Tensorflow\models\research\object_detection\metrics\coco_evaluation.py", line 28, in <module>
    from object_detection.utils import object_detection_evaluation
  File "D:\RealTimeObjectDetection\Tensorflow\models\research\object_detection\utils\object_detection_evaluation.py", line 46, in <module>
    from object_detection.utils import label_map_util
  File "D:\RealTimeObjectDetection\Tensorflow\models\research\object_detection\utils\label_map_util.py", line 29, in <module>
    from object_detection.protos import string_int_label_map_pb2
  File "D:\RealTimeObjectDetection\Tensorflow\models\research\object_detection\protos\string_int_label_map_pb2.py", line 9, in <module>
    from google.protobuf import runtime_version as _runtime_version
ImportError: cannot import name 'runtime_version' from 'google.protobuf' (C:\Users\varda\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\google\protobuf\__init__.py)

Is it a version error? also I tried to set a PYTHONPATH variable in User variables but the compiler is still looking into site-packages for object_detection file, whereas I set the path to a different location in D drive

Can you post a code snippet which reproduces the error?  Along with a requirements.txt file and the version of python which you are using?

I got a similar error from google-cloud-bigquery-storage==2.25.0 which I resolved with a pip install --upgrade protobuf, which gave me protobuf==5.27.2.  Downgrading protobuf less than 5 produces the error and upgrading it above 5 fixes it.
google-cloud-bigquery-storage isn't declaring its dependency properly.
Try installing protobuf>5

I ran that command but now I'm getting this error:
from official.vision.image_classification.efficientnet import efficientnet_model ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'official'

Sorry @varda I'm not using that module.  I'm just guessing, but does installing https://pypi.org/project/tf-models-official/ help?

The problem for me was in the version used to compile the proto files. I changed fixed the following:

grpcio-tools==1.64.1

Then I recompiled the proto files.

The issue for me was that I was using a shebang that bypassed the pyenv:
#!/usr/bin/python3
You should always use:
#!/usr/bin/env python3

The recent release of NumPy 2.0 caused some trouble with packages that rely on an older version of NumPy. To see which version of numpy is installed, run
pip list
in the command line. Example output:
Package Version
------- -------
numpy   2.0.0
pip     24.1

To downgrade to an older version:
pip install numpy==1.26.4

This advice is sometimes useful, but did you confirm that it actually solves OP's problem?

@joanis tbh it was a guess, based on the observation that the stack trace included paths to a tensorflow package, which requires numpy. I admit that the answer by Steven Ensslen is more likely to solve the problem, but I can't exclude the possibility that at least someone encountering this problem can solve it by downgrading numpy.

When I'm posting similar guesses at solutions, I prefer to leave them as comments than answers, especially since they're likely to get downvoted or deleted as answers, but ok.
